# Rails form on index page not passing params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently only have two controller methods: index and create

I've got a form on the index page. I want it to resolve to my create method in the controller. It seems to actually be resolving there as a new object is created and saved in the database, but the single parameter I have is not passed on. It shows as nil in the db.

I have a lot to learn about Rails and the conventions used. I don't think it's a routing issue, since the objects are being created. Just have no params getting pushed.

Here's my controller:

```
class MitchismsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @mitchisms = Mitchism.all
    @mitchism = Mitchism.new
end

def create
    @mitchism = Mitchism.new(params[:mitchsim])
    @mitchism.save
    redirect_to mitchisms_path
end

end
```

And here's my view:

```
<h1>Mitchisms</h1>

<%= form_for(@mitchism) do |f| %>
<ul>
    <% @mitchism.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
        <li><%= error %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>

<p>
    <%= f.label :body, "Add your Mitchism:" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :body %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>


<% @mitchisms.each do |mitchism| %>
    <div id="mitchisms">
        <%= mitchism.body %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You have a typo `params[:mitchism]`

Comment: juanpastas is correct, that's what's creating a `nil` attribute, since you're passing in params that don't exist (which evaluate to `nil`). Also you should probably add some validations to your model http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html and update the code as kiddorails suggests.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I feel like an idiot that it was a typo. I will rewrite my controller as per kiddorails' suggestion as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite got what you mean by *"but the single parameter I have is not passed on"*. If your objects are being created (as you said), how can your database be nil? `Mitchism.all` must give back all the saved objects.

And, this is how your controller must look like:

```
class MitchismsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @mitchisms = Mitchism.all
    @mitchism = Mitchism.new #creates a new object
  end

  #after form is submitted, it will reach to create action below
  def create
    @mitchism = Mitchism.new(params[:mitchism])
    if @mitchism.save
      redirect_to mitchisms_path
    else
      render 'index'
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score -2):

In your index,  since this is the last statement, that's value you will always get.

```
@mitchism = Mitchism.new.
```

You probably want to find it rathan create it in your index

```
@mitchism = Mitchism.find(params[:mitchsim])
```

Comment: you should not call find in create method, as far as I remember and think